# Integral-Fourier sum

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, fourier-analysis, definite-integrals

I am trying to prove the following relation in (3) where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta,\omega \in \mathbb{R}$.  Given the integral

$$
I=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\alpha dx \left( \beta \big(y'(x)\big)^2+\epsilon y^2\right), \quad \quad \quad (1)
$$
using a Fourier Mode decomposition
$$
y(\omega)=\int_0^\alpha dx e^{i\omega x}  y(x),\quad \quad \quad (2) 
$$
show that the integral becomes 
$$
I=\frac{1}{2\alpha} \sum_\omega \big( \beta \omega^2+\epsilon\big)\big( y^2(\omega)\big) \quad \quad \quad (3)
$$
where $\omega=\pm 2\pi n/\alpha, n=0,\pm 1,\pm 2,...$.
 I am having trouble proving (3).  I tried just plugging (2) into (1), but didn't get anywhere after
$$
I=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\alpha dx \left(\beta\big(-i\omega\big)^2+\epsilon y^2(\omega)  \right)=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\alpha dx \left(\beta \omega^2+\epsilon y^2(\omega)   \right)
$$
It seems this integral becomes a sum along with a factor of $\alpha^{-1}$, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the inverse Fourier transform, and please use different symbols for the function and its Fourier transform. If
$$
Y(ω)=\int_0^α e^{i ω x} \, y(x) \,dx,\tag{2}
$$
then
$$
y(x)=\frac1{2π}\int_{-∞}^∞e^{-i ω x} \,Y(ω)\,dω\tag4
$$
and
$$
y'(x)=\frac1{2π}\int_{-∞}^∞(-iω)e^{-i ω x} \,Y(ω)\,dω\tag5
$$